# How to put HTML anchor tags horizontally and underlined separately

Tags: html

Hi I would like to put two anchor tags next to each other but apparently they are bothe underlined with one line. how can i achieve something as shown in picture below using only html.

[two anchor tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQxn4.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<a href="somelink">Exercise 1</a>&nbsp;<a href="someotherlink">Exercise 2</a>` ?

Comment: Please try something ,at least google things.. i am sure you will find something

Answer (score 0):

Try this ......

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .wrapper {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="">Link1 </a>
        <a href="">Link2</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```